# Pattern Builder Múltiplos retornos

Tags: java, design-pattern

Tenho uma classe *builder* que é responsável por retornar um objeto que ele constrói:

```
public class ObjetoBuilder {

    private Objeto objeto; 

    public ObjetoBuilder() {
        objeto = new Objeto();
    }

    public ObjetoBuilder adicionarId(Long id) {
        if (id != null) objeto.setId(id);
        return this;
    }

    public Objeto constroi() {
        return objeto;
    }
}
```

**Dúvida**

É uma boa prática ter mais de um método constrói em um *builder*?
Por exemplo:

```
public class ObjetoBuilder {
    ...
    public Objeto controi() {
        return objeto;
    }

    public List<Objeto> constroiLista(){
        return Arrays.asList(objeto);
    }

    public String constroiJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(objeto);
    }

    public String controiXml() {
        return new XStream().toXML(objeto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os métodos `constroiJson`, `constroiLista` e `constroiXml` da tua classe `ObjetoBuilder` não constroem objetos da classe `Objeto`, logo não fazem parte do Design Pattern. Eles poderiam fazer parte da classe `Objeto`, pois apenas convertem o objeto em String em diferentes formatos (ou em lista, no caso do `constroiLista`).

Também podes utilizar uma classe helper, que trate da conversão não só para objetos classe `Objeto`, mas que seja algo genético para qualquer classe (evitando duplicação de código). Eu, particularmente, gosto mais dessa opção.

Comment: No caso o que seria essa classe "helper"? Tem algum padrão onde eu possa buscar essas referências?

Comment: No meu ponto de vista além de o objeto ser construído ele esta sendo serializado, no caso recebendo um plus, minha dúvida é se esse plus sai do padrão ou se pode ser feito.

Comment: Sim, sai do padrão. E sim, pode ser feito - cada caso é um caso, padrões são guias para ajudar, e não para engessar o projeto. Melhor é que que se avalie caso a caso.

Comment: Digamos que tu tenhas 3 classes que desejas serializar com formato Json. Não é bom que tu implementes 3 métodos iguais (ou quase iguais) para a mesma função. Então, tu podes criar uma classe auxiliar (helper) que contenha um método `toJson` que receba como parâmetro qualquer dos objetos e os converta para Json. Assim tu não replicas bugs, simplifica testes, diminui possibilidades de falhas...